# Checking if exist email/cell number when resetting password

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to check if the user 'email' or 'number' exists when the user is tring to change password if forgotten. Below is the form enter code here:

Email or Cellphone
                                    
                                   
                                                       
                            
                                
                                    
                                        
                                    
                                
                                
                                    
                                        Already have an Account.?

User exist function check:

```
public function checkUserExits($field){
        $userExists = User::where('email', $field)->orWhere('cellphone',$field)->first();
        return $userExists;
    }
```

when running on local server getting an error message "Triying to get property "email"
of non-object." the problem is that when i remove check to see if just email exist the same code works.

Answer (score 0):

dd($field) and check what result you are getting.

from below one of the query should work

$userExists = User::where('email', $field->email)->orWhere('cellphone',$field->cellphone)->first();

$userExists = User::where('email',$field['email'])->orWhere('cellphone',$field['cellphone'])->first();